# Article or paragraph 47/1 pronunciation question

Tags: reading-aloud

How should I pronounce **47/1**?

> India abstained on resolution **47/1** of 22 September 1992.

Comment: I don't know what 47/1 is referring to but article sounds more official.. Can you post a link to 47/1? Or are you asking how to say something shown as 47/1, like how to verbalise a slash in general? It's usually "of".

Comment: Please cite the source of the text you're asking about.

Comment: https://research.un.org/en/docs/ga/resolutions

Answer (score 2):

Given this appears to be a UN resolution, it would seem best to use "slash", as used when the UN votes.

Examples of the UN voting:
https://youtu.be/hbA3aTH3Gb0
or
https://youtu.be/JL-Jf1pciok

But you could use "dash", nothing or "session 47 resolution 1", and there are probably other ways of saying this too.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is "forty-seven slash one". But organizations that pass resolutions tend to have their own conventions, so it depends on the context. For example, it might be pronounced "forty-seven, one". Or the slash could be a shorthand for something, like "forty-seven, section one". There's not a single definitive answer.